# What's the fastest way to search for a type by name among loaded assemblies?

Tags: c#, performance, reflection

I'm writing a small templating language (much like Razor) and one of the things I have to do on template compilation is to resolve CLR enums based on either (1) a fully qualified name or (2) an unqualified name + a namespace. For example:

```
namespace Foo.Bar {
    public enum MyEnum { A, B }
}

// template:
@using Foo.Bar;
@using System;
...
@Foo.Bar.MyEnum.A // fully qualified
@MyEnum.A // unqualified, but in one of the specified namespaces
```

My current approach is to scan all assemblies in the current app domain for the enum, which looks something like the following:

```
string[] namespaces = // parsed from template
string typeName = // parsed from template
string fieldName = // parsed from template

var possibleResolutions = from type in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
        .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    where type.IsEnum
    from @namespace in namespaces
    let fullName = @namespace + '.' + typeName
    // the replace is because nested enum types (like we have in AptOne, will have a fullname of namespace.OuterClass+InnerClass)
    where type.FullName.Replace('+', '.') == fullName
    let field = type.GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    where field != null;
```

I've found that this can be quite slow on cold startup (dominating all other template compilation time), with nearly all of the time spent in GetTypes(). I'm wondering, is there a faster way to do such lookups?

Note that I'm already caching these results, so I'm not interested in that sort of solution.

Comment: There's a [good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3a58006.aspx) on building your own custom binder on MSDN, but I think you are going to have to live with slowness if you are trying to load every single type from every single assembly within the assembly scope. Of course, you could always use [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx) and have the .NET compiler handle all the type lookups for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting, I've found that `Assembly.GetType(string)` is much, much faster than `Assembly.GetTypes().Where(...)`. Thus, I've solved my performance problem by making a bunch of targeted name lookups and avoiding looking at all types:

```
var result = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
.Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
.SelectMany(
            // possible full names is a list which tries replacing each . in the name with a +
            // starting from the end
    a => possibleFullNames.Select(t => new { t.@namespace, type = a.GetType(t.fullName) })
)
.Where(t => t.type != null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Common Compiler Infrastructure](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) to scan the assemblies without reflection, to make a list of the enums. From their site:

> The CCI Metadata API allows applications to efficiently analyze or modify .NET assemblies, modules, and debugging (PDB) files. CCI Metadata supports the functionality of the .NET System.Reflection and System.Reflection.Emit APIs, but with much better performance. It also provides additional functionality that is not available in either .NET API.

Then if you need the actual types you can use your list with calls to `Assembly.GetType()`.